# How to set Jexcel name in Spring mvc?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jexcelapi, jexl

I'm following with [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-export-data-to-excel-file-via-abstractjexcelview/) Jexcel with Spring tutorial and everything looks fine.it can create excel file and write sheet except one thing is I can't change my excel file name? It will display file name same as my link to controller.

**Here is example**

```
<li><h3><a href="report.html">Jexcel Showcase</a></h3></li>
```

It will always create excel file name "report.html.xls". Anyone know how to change file name??

**This is my controller**

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        //dummy data
        revenueData.put("Jan-2010", "$100,000,000");
        revenueData.put("Feb-2010", "$110,000,000");
        revenueData.put("Mar-2010", "$130,000,000");
        revenueData.put("Apr-2010", "$140,000,000");
        revenueData.put("May-2010", "$200,000,000");
    return new ModelAndView("jexcelSuccess","revenueData",revenueData);
}
```

**and buildExcelDocument method**

```
protected void buildExcelDocument(Map model, WritableWorkbook workbook,
   HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   throws Exception {

   Map<String,String> revenueData = (Map<String,String>) model.get("revenueData");
   WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Revenue Report", 0);
   WritableSheet sheet2 = workbook.createSheet("Test Report", 1);
   WritableSheet sheet3 = workbook.createSheet("Hello Report", 2);

       sheet.addCell(new Label(0, 0, "Month"));
       sheet.addCell(new Label(1, 0, "Revenue"));

       int rowNum = 1;
   for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : revenueData.entrySet()) {
    //create the row data
    sheet.addCell(new Label(0, rowNum, entry.getKey()));
        sheet.addCell(new Label(1, rowNum, entry.getValue()));
        rowNum++;
       }
   }
```

Thank in advance,
Mart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to the controller:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"whatEver.xls\"");
```

Comment: Thank you,Ralph.

You're help me again. :)